# Find the first signal in a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) with different "price"s and I want to compare these prices and make a decision.

`df['Decision'] = np.where((df['price1'] > df['price2']) ,'sell',np.where((df['price1'] < df['price2']),'buy',np.nan))`

My output is:

| price1 | price2 | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 50 | NaN |
| 100 | 200 | buy |
| 70 | 140 | buy |
| 150 | 200 | buy |
| 150 | 50 | sell |
| 60 | 20 | sell |

But I want to have just the "first signal" of "buy" or "sell" and **delete replication until the next signal**, as:

| price1 | price2 | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 50 | NaN |
| 100 | 200 | buy |
| 70 | 140 |  |
| 150 | 200 |  |
| 150 | 50 | sell |
| 60 | 20 |  |

Comment: It solves my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269453/pandas-replace-duplicates-with-nan-and-keep-row

Comment: So mark the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas-series-idxmax):

```
df.loc[(df['price1'] > df['price2']).idxmax(), 'Decision'] = 'sell'
df.loc[(df['price1'] < df['price2']).idxmax(), 'Decision'] = 'buy'
```

Comment: It gets the first table, not the second. I don't want to have the same signals until the decision changing.